# is it good to store HLS .m3u8 file with its segment files .ts in cassandra database?

Tags: node.js, database, ffmpeg, cassandra

I am working on video streaming app, where backend is nodejs , so i want to upload a heavy video file(may be 1gb) and convert to .m3u8 file with its segment .ts file by using FFMPEG and then i want to store them all on cassandra , is it good to do that , if not please anyone suggest any solution and yeah I wants to avoid cloud storage like azure and google cloud for cost saving purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store images and videos as a CQL `blob` type but they were designed for small [binary] files.

Although it is possible to store blobs as large as 2GB, the recommended blob size is 1MB for optimal performance.

If you're interested, I've answered a similar question before and provided the pros and cons in this post -- https://community.datastax.com/questions/7755/. Cheers!

Comment: so you saying that put all my metadata like urls of files in cassandra database and the files itself of .m3u8 and .ts for stream in s3 or google cloud ?

Answer (score 0):

An [Object storage solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_storage) is better suited than any database for large blobs.

More information: [Is it a bad practice to store large files (10 MB) in a database?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/150787/37888)